# JSP - how to group enums via a selector?

Tags: java, jsp, drop-down-menu, enums

I have an enum X (Java) with 13 different values. In my web page (JSP) the user should be able to choose one of X via a drop down. As it is quite a long list, I'd like to group X values and select the group first via a drop down or radio buttons.

What is an effective way to achieve this?

- Do I need another enum for the groups, that hold the related X values or do I use it only in the JSP-File?
- Is there a way to dynamically retrieve the selection of the group to show/hide the second dropdown (that contains parts of X)?
- Is there a way to do this without reloading the page?

Both enum X, the groups and their connection are static.

Comment: if you can group those values wouldn't it better to simply create 1 enum for each grup instead of having 13 in one enum and then groups in another?

Comment: @FilipRistic I don't know if I expressed myself correctly. I've got 1 enum with 13 different values like A{1,2,3} B{2,3,4}, ..., M{9,9,9} and for the input page I want to select Group 1 ~> Dropdown consists of A-D; Group 2 -> E&F and so on. I don't need the groups in my program, I need the enum. Just for displaying I want to group them.

Comment: maybe add a group number to each enum.